# Cross Domain Messaging of different apps on different Ports

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use postMessage( ) to send message from one app to another. 
One of my app is on liberty server with port 9080 and another on tomcat with port 8080. 
When I try it with same app, I can post the message but with differents apps on same server or on different server, its not working. The window is getting opened up, but the content is not displayed.

Following are my Files-

1) Parent App (App from which i send my content)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function Menu() {
      var opener=window.open("http://localhost:9080/Ancillary/index.jsp");
  opener.postMessage('Hello', 'http://localhost:9080');
    //opener.callback(document.getElementById("textField").value);
}
 </script>
 <button id="send" onclick="Menu();">Try it !</button>'
```

2) Child App (Which receives the Message)

```
<script>
function receiver(event) {
         if (event.origin == 'http://localhost:9080') {
         console.log(event.data+' recieved by parent');
        alert(event.data+' recieved by parent');
  }
}
   window.addEventListener("message", receiver, false);
 </script>
  <p>This is an Example!</p>
```

Right now I am trying to make it work on same server with different apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable CORS in your Web Api. The easier and preferred way to enable CORS globally is to add the following into web.xml

```
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
<param-value>Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Last-Modified</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: web.config, you meant to say web.xml, because I am working on a maven web project right now.